# Hibernate and sql server -- select IN with 8000 items

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

We have a query that does a sql server select with IN that we had originally anticipated a few items (under 20?) -- now it's being asked for 8000.  This causes a timeout.

Hibernate generates the query just fine, but as I understand it, sql server doesn't optimize for more than 64 items in an IN query at a time and performance falls off after that.  We've proved this running some queries manually -- first result of 64 takes ~5 seconds, the rest comes in 2 seconds.  The raw query takes minutes to complete.

Is there some way to tell hibernate to break this up or can (should?) I write some kind of extension/plugin for hibernate that says "if you ask for more than 64 items, break those up, thread them, stitch them back together"?

Comment: Put the 8000 items into a separate table and join to it.

Comment: Are these 8000 items coming from the UI (or something like that)?  We could rewrite the query to use a separate table perhaps.

Comment: With ADO.NET i'd use table valued parameters, but i think they're not spported by hibernate because they are sql-server specific.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, its a bunch of not-keys but they are indexed.  As best we know, it'll grow, maybe to something silly.  We talked about making a view to handle it.  Not an ideal thing because we're finding out this might actually be the cause of numerous performance issues and we kind of want to fix it for all of the things we're doing

Comment: @jeriley Why use a view rather than a permanent indexed table?  Is there a reason not to do this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen my opinion -- poor table design. I'm no sql grand master but it's obvious this is land of "just add one more column" so it's used by a bunch of other services.  The data inside of it is like sku's but change upon revision so the numbers change frequently enough.  Those 8000 (or how many ever) isn't a static list, it'll change each call they make.  Worse case we're looking at a stored procedure